# how to clear the back stack on intent load

Tags: android, back-stack

I have a log in system in my app, and I would like to make it so that once the user logs into their account the back stack get's cleared, so they cannot see the log in activity, unless they click on the log out button in the main activity. How would I accomplish this?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `finish()` method to destroy your login activity after intent. It'll be removed from stack as well.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourAccountActivity.class);
startActivity(i);

// destroying your current activity
finish();
```

If you don't want to put this activity in the stack, you can also use

`android:noHistory="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

When you change the activity, this activity won't be in the stack.

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical
>   trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the
>   user will not be able to return to it.

Another option is to use IntentFlags.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourAccountActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: first off thanks for your quick reply. I really appreciate the help. I do have one question: what if i have two activities before the main activity and I want to clear both at the same time?

Comment: thank you very much! that goes above and beyond... much appreciated. I now feel like I have a good understanding of the back stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually finish two activity at a same time then you can use ApplicationContext class and in that define.

MyApplicationClass.java

```
public Activity homeActivity = null;
public Activity otherActivity = null;
```

and when you start Homeactivity you can do in onCreate() method :

HomeActivity.java

```
private MyApplicationClass myApplication = null;

   myApplication = (MyApplicationClass )getApplicationContext();

   myApplication.homeActivity = HomeActivity.this;
```

Same in otheractivity's onCreate() method:

otheractivity.java

```
private MyApplicationClass myApplication = null;

       myApplication = (MyApplicationClass )getApplicationContext();

       myApplication.otherActivity = otheractivity.this;
```

And when you want to finish Homeactivity and otheractivity at a same time then 
You can finish like this way..

```
myApplication.homeActivity.finish();
myApplication.otherActivity.finish();
```